# C++ multiple object recognition

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I am working on a multi-object recognition program. I have succeeded recognising two objects. However, the speed of my program is really slow and laggy. Can somebody please tell a way to speed the program up?

So far, I have seen that ORB is quite fast at matching features. However, my program is still too slow. I have also noticed that there are three for loops, possibly making the program slow down. Interestingly on YouTube, I have seen videos where the output is really smooth.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2));

void ttea(vector<KeyPoint> bwImgKP, Mat objectDS, Mat bwImgDS, vector<KeyPoint> objectKP, vector<Point2f> objectCRN, Mat colorImg, string text)
{
    vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;
    vector<DMatch> matchesGD;
    vector<Point2f> obj;
    vector<Point2f> scene;
    vector<Point2f> sceneCRN(4);
    Mat H;

    if (bwImgKP.empty() || objectDS.empty() || bwImgDS.empty())
    {
        return;
    }

    matcher.knnMatch(objectDS, bwImgDS, matches, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < min(bwImgDS.rows - 1, (int)matches.size()); i++)
    {
        if ((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int)matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int)matches[i].size() > 0))
        {
            matchesGD.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }

    if (matchesGD.size() >= 4)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matchesGD.size(); i++)
        {
            obj.push_back(objectKP[matchesGD[i].queryIdx].pt);
            scene.push_back(bwImgKP[matchesGD[i].trainIdx].pt);
        }

        H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

        perspectiveTransform(objectCRN, sceneCRN, H);

        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[0], sceneCRN[1], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[1], sceneCRN[2], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[2], sceneCRN[3], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[3], sceneCRN[0], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        putText(colorImg, text, sceneCRN[1], FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);
    }
}

int main()
{
    OrbFeatureDetector detector;
    OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;

    VideoCapture capture(0);

    Mat object0 = imread("Much Ado About Nothing.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<KeyPoint> object0KP;
    detector.detect(object0, object0KP);

    Mat object0DS;
    extractor.compute(object0, object0KP, object0DS);

    vector<Point2f> object0CRN(4);
    object0CRN[0] = (cvPoint(0, 0));
    object0CRN[1] = (cvPoint(object0.cols, 0));
    object0CRN[2] = (cvPoint(object0.cols, object0.rows));
    object0CRN[3] = (cvPoint(0, object0.rows));

    Mat object1 = imread("Popular Science.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<KeyPoint> object1KP;
    detector.detect(object1, object1KP);

    Mat object1DS;
    extractor.compute(object1, object1KP, object1DS);

    vector<Point2f> object1CRN(4);
    object1CRN[0] = (cvPoint(0, 0));
    object1CRN[1] = (cvPoint(object1.cols, 0));
    object1CRN[2] = (cvPoint(object1.cols, object1.rows));
    object1CRN[3] = (cvPoint(0, object1.rows));

    while (true)
    {
        Mat bwImg;
        Mat bwImgDS;
        vector<KeyPoint> bwImgKP;

        Mat colorImg;
        capture.read(colorImg);

        cvtColor(colorImg, bwImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        detector.detect(bwImg, bwImgKP);
        extractor.compute(bwImg, bwImgKP, bwImgDS);

        ttea(bwImgKP, object0DS, bwImgDS, object0KP, object0CRN, colorImg, "Play");
        ttea(bwImgKP, object1DS, bwImgDS, object1KP, object1CRN, colorImg, "Magazine");

        imshow("Fish Smart", colorImg);

        if (waitKey(1) == 27)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Intro

I'm not an expert "well-versed in the art", so this is mostly a style review of the C++ code rather than providing the performance-improving hints that you're really looking for; I hope someone else will step up with those insights for you!

### Headers and namespaces

We don't seem to be using `<stdio.h>` or `<iostream>`, but do require `<vector>` and `<string>`.

My system doesn't have `"opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"`, but it doesn't seem to be required.

Unless your OpenCV headers are installed into a non-standard location, it's probably better to include them with `<>` rather than `""`.

The only thing we're using from the `std` namespace is `std::vector` and a solitary `std::string`, so we can be a lot more specific about what we import.

More arguably, we might be more specific about `cv` at file scope and only bring in the entire namespace within the functions.  For this small program, it's reasonably to import all of `namespace cv` at file scope, so I'll leave that as is.

We now have:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;

using std::vector;
```

### Globals

Does `matcher` need to be a global variable?  Perhaps it could be a static variable within `ttea()`?  Perhaps it would be better as a non-static local variable - that would allow `ttea()` to be called concurrently from multiple threads, which would significantly help with your performance problems.  Perhaps a thread-local variable is the right compromise?  I've no idea what the construction cost of a `cv::FlannBasedMatcher` is, so it's hard for me to give a solid recommendation here, but you could ask the questions above and work out the best choice from that.

### `ttea()` function

I've no idea what the name `ttea` means - is it obvious to someone likely to be solving the same problem?  If not, consider a more descriptive name, or at least a comment.  The same goes for its formal parameter names.

I think it's better to declare variables where they are needed - we're writing C++, not (old) C.

This loop looks a bit strange:

```
for (int i = 0;  i < min(bwImgDS.rows - 1, (int)matches.size());  i++)
```

It's not clear where `bwImgDS.rows` comes into this.  Is it just an optimisation?  It might be possible to write this as a standard range-based loop:

```
for (const auto& match: matches)
```

perhaps with a `break` if there's a need to terminate early.  If it can't be re-written as a range-based `for`, I'd still advise writing `i++` as a postincrement rather than as a preincrement: although it should be equivalent here, defaulting to this form is a good habit that can avert surprises when incrementing non-primitive types.

The condition within the loop confuses me:

```
    if ((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int)matches[i].size() <= 2 && (int)matches[i].size() > 0))
```

I don't know where that constant `0.6` comes from - is it a tunable, or is it a fundamental constant in the algorithm?  Either way, it deserves to be named.  In the other expressions, it doesn't make sense to cast `size_t` to `int` and then compare against zero - we should be able to safely write `matches[i].size() <= 2`.  Given that we're accessing elements 0 and 1, it probably makes sense to test `matches[i].size()` exactly equal to 2 as the first test:

```
    if (matches[i].size() == 2  &&  matches[i][0].distance < 0.6 * matches[i][1].distance)
```

Later, when we iterate over `matchesGD`, we can avoid a warning by making `i` a `size_t` rather than `int`:

```
    for (std::size_t i = 0;  i < matchesGD.size();  ++i)
```

But this is easily converted to range-based form.

The most helpful thing we can change in `ttea()` is to reduce the amount of copying of its parameters.  Everything except `colorImg` can be passed as reference to const object:

```
void ttea(const vector<KeyPoint>& bwImgKP,
          const Mat& objectDS,
          const Mat& bwImgDS,
          const vector<KeyPoint>& objectKP,
          const vector<Point2f>& objectCRN,
          Mat colorImg,
          const std::string& text)
{
    if (bwImgKP.empty() || objectDS.empty() || bwImgDS.empty())
        return;

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher(new flann::LshIndexParams(20, 10, 2));
    vector<vector<DMatch>> matches;
    matcher.knnMatch(objectDS, bwImgDS, matches, 2);

    vector<DMatch> matchesGD;
    for (int i = 0;  i < bwImgDS.rows - 1 && i < (int)matches.size();  ++i)
    {
        const auto& match = matches[i];
        if (match.size() == 2  &&  match[0].distance < 0.6 * match[1].distance)
            matchesGD.push_back(match[0]);
    }

    if (matchesGD.size() >= 4)
    {
        vector<Point2f> obj;
        vector<Point2f> scene;
        for (const auto& match: matchesGD)
        {
            obj.push_back(objectKP[match.queryIdx].pt);
            scene.push_back(bwImgKP[match.trainIdx].pt);
        }

        auto H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

        vector<Point2f> sceneCRN(4);
        perspectiveTransform(objectCRN, sceneCRN, H);

        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[0], sceneCRN[1], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[1], sceneCRN[2], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[2], sceneCRN[3], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        line(colorImg, sceneCRN[3], sceneCRN[0], Scalar(255, 0, 0), 4);
        putText(colorImg, text, sceneCRN[1],
                FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1, 8);
    }
}
```

### `main()` function

As I don't have the required input images, I have less to say about `main()`, other than noting that

```
while (true) {
    ...
    if (condition)
        break;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
do {
    ...
} while (!condition);
```

So the final loop could be

```
do {
    Mat bwImg;
    Mat bwImgDS;
    vector<KeyPoint> bwImgKP;

    Mat colorImg;
    capture.read(colorImg);

    cvtColor(colorImg, bwImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    detector.detect(bwImg, bwImgKP);
    extractor.compute(bwImg, bwImgKP, bwImgDS);

    ttea(bwImgKP, object0DS, bwImgDS, object0KP, object0CRN, colorImg, "Play");
    ttea(bwImgKP, object1DS, bwImgDS, object1KP, object1CRN, colorImg, "Magazine");

    imshow("Fish Smart", colorImg);
} while (waitKey(1) != 27);
```